# ERROR: expect@29.6.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0". Got "12.22.12"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I've been receiving this error

```bash
error expect@29.6.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0". Got "12.22.12"        
error Found incompatible module.
```

This **`expect`** library used by the **jest** package. By viewing the **`node_modules`** folder the expect package version is **`26.6.2`** but the error is generated by **`29.6.1`** version. Although, this version **`29.6.1`** isn't used anywhere in the project it is still generating this node version incompatible error. I cannot update the node version cause other dependencies in the project will get affected. How can I resolve this issue?

I tried running to check which version of expect is dependent to which dependency.

```
npm ls expect
```

The result was like this

```bash
yarn why v1.17.3
[1/4] Why do we have the module "expect"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
[4/4] Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "expect@26.6.2"
info Has been hoisted to "expect"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "workspace-aggregator-0ca060b9-5530-4147-845d-6bce9cd2005f" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest-snapshot#expect"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest-runtime#@jest#globals#expect"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest-config#jest-jasmine2#expect"
info Disk size without dependencies: "244KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1.55MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "7.34MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 68
=> Found "jest-circus#expect@27.5.1"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "_project_#jest-circus" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest-circus#jest-snapshot#expect"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest-circus#jest-runtime#@jest#globals#expect"
info Disk size without dependencies: "236KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1.45MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "7.32MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 67
=> Found "jest#expect@27.4.6"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "_project_#jest#@jest#core#jest-snapshot" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest#@jest#core#jest-snapshot#expect"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest#@jest#core#jest-runtime#@jest#globals#expect"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest#@jest#core#jest-config#jest-jasmine2#expect"
info Disk size without dependencies: "236KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1.45MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "7.32MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 67
=> Found "jest-cli#expect@27.4.6"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "_project_#jest#jest-cli#jest-config#jest-jasmine2" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest#jest-cli#jest-config#jest-jasmine2#expect"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest#jest-cli#@jest#core#jest-snapshot#expect"
   - Hoisted from "_project_#jest#jest-cli#@jest#core#jest-runtime#@jest#globals#expect"
info Disk size without dependencies: "236KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1.45MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "7.32MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 67
Done in 1.74s.
```

Comment: Are you using node 12 as the error says? If so, is it possible to upgrade it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using node 12 but its not possible to upgrade it since other dependencies will be  affected.

Comment: try renaming `node_modules` to `node_modules2` (no need to delete) and install all dependencies again to see if something is broken there. Possibly regenerate the `yarn.lock` file (rename it to `yarn.lock2` or something else, again, no need to delete it).